# Rename PF-SRC file record name

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange

Can someone tell me how to rename the record name of a `PF-SRC`?
Like: `MYLIB/QRPGSRC` has record format `QDDSSRC`. I want to change it to `QRPGSRC`.

I tried `CHGPF` and `CHGSRCPF` but there was no option for record name.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can change a record format name for a file. If you create a new source physical file named QRPGSRC, the record format will be QRPGSRC. If you simply duplicate a file and change it's name, the record format name will be different from the file name.

So your best bet will be to create a new source file with the appropriate name, and copy the members from the old file to the new file.